# Help with Mule Magento Connector

Tags: web-services, magento, mule, connector

I have been trying for a while to get working the Mule's Magento Cloud Connector. However I have had no success.

I am using magento 1.6.0, mule 3.1.2, and the Mule's Magento Cloud Connector 1.2.

My code and the error stack that I'm getting after trying to execute it is in here:
http://forums.mulesoft.org/thread.jspa?threadID=6286

I appreciate any help you can provide me

Regards
Leo

Comment: I see that a SOAP fault occurs ("Server.userException") but this fault is not handled properly by the Magento connector, which then dies in a fire. I have attempted to fix the fault handling so you'd hopefully get better error reporting and thus pinpoint your issue easier. Try: https://github.com/downloads/ddossot/magento-connector/mule-module-magento-1.3-SNAPSHOT.jar

Comment: Hello David, Thank you so much for your help. Thanks to you I have managed to find the cause of my problem. The exception I got is "Processing instructions are not allowed within SOAP messages". I have googled it and found that it is commonly thrown when the endpoint returns an HTML error page instead of a soap response. If this is the case, is there a way I can catch this html page so I know exactly what is happening?

Comment: Either use TCPMon (as a proxy between Mule and Magento) or WireShark (to monitor network traffice) to see what's this bogus HTML response you're receiving.

Comment: Thanks for answering again David. You have no idea how much you've helped me. I'm going to try wireshark now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found my problem. The connector's documentation is not clear about which address you should use when configuring it. I was using .http://mymagentohost/. But the address that should be used was .http://mymagentohost/index.php/api/v2_soap/ or .http://mymagentohost/index.php/api/soap/ in case of using the first version of the API.

Regards
Leo

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution :

https://sashistore.gostorego.com + /api/v2_soap?wsdl
is url

Username and API key will allows you to connect using Magento connector

For Reference Please go through : http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/introduction.html